# usage of an indefinite article

Tags: definite-articles

I'm stuck on the sentence.

May we put an indefinite article in the sentence below if we talk about the object in general?

Here is the example:

- Is it possible to find out the height of a triangle if we know the length of its sides?

Here is the article ***a*** after the preposition of and I'm not sure is it correct.
Could you point out my other mistakes if I made?

Answer (score 1):

What you have is absolutely correct. It is very polite of you to ask our permission (May we...), so I am happy to say "Yes, you may." Most English users (uncouth as we are) would just say "Can we..." (Are we able to...), which gets the job done, I suppose, but not nearly as elegantly.

Edit: You can omit the article if you talk about triangles in general:

> Is it possible to find out the height of triangles if we know the
>   lengths of their sides?

Comment: but if we omit the article in the sentence, will it change the meaning of it?

Comment: If you omit the article, the sentence would be ungrammatical, but see my edit.